# year duration algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, duration

I'm making a program that needs the duration (in `time_t`) of a year.

In other ways, `time_t` of DD/MM/YYYY + duration = `time_t` of DD/MM/YYYY+1

So it may not always be 365 days (and 29/02/2012 will become 28/02/2013)

Here's the algorithm I came with :

```
if YEAR is leap than
    if we are before the 29th feb' than return 365+1 days
    else if we are the 29th feb' than return 365-1 days
    else return 365 days
else if YEAR+1 is leap than
    if we are before or the 28th feb' than return 365 days
    else return 365+1 days
else return 365 days
```

Here, a day is 60 * 60 * 24 seconds

This algorithm seems to work. But I was wondering if there were another way to do this without all theses conditions and only 2 possible return values, or just some "trick" to optimize the thing.

I tried to increment `tm_year` from the `struct tm` like this :

```
// t is the input time_t
struct tm Tm (*localtime(&t));
if (Tm.tm_mon == 2 && Tm.tm_mday == 29) --Tm.tm_mday;
++Tm.tm_year;
return mktime(&Tm) - t;
```

But the result isn't what I want, I got -1 hour, or -25...

I guess it's because a year is not exactly 365 * 24 * 60 * 60.

Comment: Leap seconds change the length of days by 1 second, but that doesn't explain 3600 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) for this, since it already implements what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>
namespace date = boost::gregorian;

int main() {
   date::date_period dp(date::date(2012, 6, 4), date::date(2013, 6, 4));
   long days = dp.length().days();
   std::cout << "Days between dates: " << days << std::endl;
```

}

If you wanted more precision, then you could use `posix_time` from Boost too:

```
namespace ptime = boost::posix_time;

...

ptime::ptime t1(date::date(2012, 6, 4), ptime::hours(0));
ptime::ptime t2(date::date(2013, 6, 4), ptime::hours(0));

ptime::time_duration td = t2 - t1;
std::cout << "Milliseconds: " << td.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;
```

Typically `time_t` is measured in seconds. Therefore, you would just need to call to `td.total_seconds()` to obtain the value that you are looking for.

Comment: Boost would be a great option, but I'm not sure if I will include this quite big library just for one functionality...

Comment: @perelo Adding a new dependency to your project is something you must carefully consider. That being said, however, I somehow already consider Boost as part of C++, since it really simplifies a lot programming in C++. Additionally, if you are programming in Linux and do not need `to_string`/`from_string` functions, then boost::date_time is just a header library (i.e., you do not need to link your program against Boost, just include a few headers).

Comment: @perelo Actually it is also a header-only dependency in Windows (unless you are using Visual C++ 6.x or Borland compilers). More info [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries).

Comment: @perelo You can have a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226206/is-there-a-reason-to-not-use-boost) for pros and cons about using Boost.

Comment: Thanks you're right, boost/date_time contains __only__ `.hpp` files, so I can just include them :)

Comment: @perelo No problem :) The good point about Boost is that you just need  to take whatever makes your life easier. You don't need to take the whole thing, unless you want to.

Answer (score 2):

```
if YEAR is leap than
    if we are before the 29th feb' than return 365+1 days
    else if we are the 29th feb' than return 365-1 days
    else return 365 days
else if YEAR+1 is leap than
    if we are before or the 28th feb' than return 365 days
    else return 365+1 days
else return 365 days
```

simplifies to:

```
if (YEAR is leap)
    if (< 29th Feb) return 365+1
    if (= 29th Feb) return 365-1
else if (YEAR+1 is leap)
    if (> 29th Feb) return 365+1

return 365
```

But why would you want to do this? It's much better to have readable code than "trick" optimizations.

As @betabandido has suggested, something like `date(year+1, mon, day) - date(year, mon, day)` would be much simpler, far more readable and able to handle leap years, leap seconds and [September missing 11 days](http://www.genealogytoday.com/columns/everyday/030902.html).

Comment: yes but using struct tm isn't working well, though I'm testing boost atm

Answer (score 0):

The length of a solar year is not a fixed number. The [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar) has invented a method to compensate for leap years which is not entirely precise. That goes "a year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4, unless it is divisible by 100, but is leap again if it is divisible by 400.

We in Iran have a [more precise calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar#In_Iran), in which the years change the second Earth makes a full circle around the sun. In the same link you can see the average solar year as 365.2422 days and mean interval between spring equinoxes as 365.2424 days.

In [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year#Length_of_tropical_year) more details are given about the length of the solar year (tropical year) in seconds.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that a year a little more than 365 days, but I'm actually not looking to find an absolute values of seconds for a Earth orbit around the Sun, thanks for the precision though.

Comment: @perelo, so what do you exactly want? The number of "days" in the year? Well that is 366 if leap year and 365 if not. You don't need to check whether today is 29 of Feb!

Comment: I need to get the number of seconds between today and the same date one year later, so it may not be a complete year

Comment: @Perelo, I see. Your `mktime` solution _should_ work, are you sure if you have tested it correctly? It doesn't make sense for it to return a time in the past, having incremented the year!

Comment: It seems that when I initialize a struct tm to a date before the 29th feb, the mktime substracts an hour!